# DRF returns 400 Bad Request

Tags: django, flutter, dart, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django Rest Framework and I am trying to send an object from a Flutter app to DRF backend.

I have a `BatchGuideDraft` and I want to send it to backend inside `POST` method but I am getting a `400 Bad Request` error.

I have either 2 problems, first one is I am not mapping the object properly on the app side; second one is I am not able to deserialize it on backend. I couldn't find the problem why and I need your help here.

This is my `BatchGuideDraft` model on Flutter side:

```
class BatchGuideDraft implements BaseRequestModel {
  final String description;
  final String frequencyTitle;
  final DateTime startDate;
  final DateTime endDate;
  final ReminderType reminderType;
  final List<DateTime> reminderDates;
  bool repeating;
  int batchID;

  BatchGuideDraft({@required this.frequencyTitle, @required this.description,
    @required this.startDate, @required this.endDate, @required this.reminderType,
    @required this.reminderDates, @required this.repeating});

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    assert(batchID != null);
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'description': description,
      'frequency_title': frequencyTitle,
      'start_date': startDate.toString(),
      'end_date': endDate.toString(),
      'reminder_type': reminderType.index.toString(),
      'reminder_dates': reminderDates.map((e) => e.toString()).toList().toString(),
      'batch': batchID.toString(),
      'repeating': repeating.toString(),
    };
  }
}
```

And this is how I try to send it:

```
Future<void> createBatchGuide(BatchGuideDraft guide) async {
    await _post(["v1", "app", "guide"], guide.toMap());
}
```

This is my `BatchGuideDraftSerializer` on API side:

```
class BatchGuideRequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    done = serializers.BooleanField(default=False)
    reminder_dates = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.DateTimeField())

    class Meta:
        model = BatchGuide
        fields = ['id', 'description', 'done', 'frequency_title', 'start_date',
                  'end_date', 'reminder_type', 'reminder_dates', 'repeating']
```

And this is my `BatchGuide` model:

```
class BatchGuide(TimeStampMixin):
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    frequency_title = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    reminder_type = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    reminder_dates = ArrayField(models.DateTimeField(), default=list)
    repeating = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    batch = models.ForeignKey(Batch, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='guides')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'batch_guides'
        ordering = ['start_date']
```

I got stuck on this and I'd be really glad if you could help me.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: have you checked body of 400 response?